# A subgroup of $\mathrm{PSU}(2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $S$ be the set of matrices $A\in\mathrm{PSU}(2)$ such that $A$ can be written as  $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& z\\\bar z&1\end{array}\right);\ \  z\in \mathbb C$.

How to show that $S$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{PSU}(2)$?

I mean how to show it is closed under multiplication, since when I multiplied  I got $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& z\\\bar z&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& w\\\bar w&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1+z\bar w& z+w\\ \bar z+\bar w&1+\bar zw\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: Have you tried the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test)?

Comment: But the problem that I don't see how it is closed. Since $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& z\\\bar z&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& w\\\bar w&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1+z\bar w& z+w\\ \bar z+\bar w&1+\bar zw\end{array}\right) $ which is not of the given form!

Comment: The $P$ in $PSU(2)$ means to take the quotient by the center, so 2-by-2 matrices are just _representatives_ for group elements.

Comment: @paulgarrett can you please explain that to me more? since I am confused

Comment: This is the third time that you have asked for a proof that this non-subgroup is a subgroup $\ddot\frown$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard model of the group $U(2)$ is the group of two-by-two complex matrices $g$ such that $g^*g=1_2$, where $g^*$ is $g$-conjugate transpose. The group $SU(2)$ is the subgroup of $U(2)$ of matrices also having determinant $1$. The center $Z$ of $SU(2)$ consists of (scalar) matrices $\pmatrix{\mu & 0 \cr 0 & \mu}$ where $|\mu|=1$. The group $PSU(2)$ is the quotient group $SU(2)/Z$. Thus, we can choose representatives for elements of $PSU(2)$ in $SU(2)$, if desired.

I have a suspicion that this is not quite what you are doing, since those special elements are not in $SU(2)$ or even $U(2)$. But those elements are still "close" to being in $SU(2)$, since if we divide by the scalar $\sqrt{1-z\bar{z}}$ (the square root of the determinant), the matrices 
$$
\pmatrix{
{1\over \sqrt{1-z\bar{z}}} & {z\over \sqrt{1-z\bar{z}}}
\cr
{\bar{z} \over \sqrt{1-z\bar{z}}} & {1\over \sqrt{1-z\bar{z}}}
}
$$
are in $SU(2)$.

Nevertheless, I think there is something amiss in the posing of the question, since, indeed, the product of two elements of that form can *not* be put back into the same form *even* if/when we are allowed to adjust by scalars.

For that matter, in a somewhat fancier context, the renormalized-by-scalars versions of your matrices are of the form $\exp\pmatrix{0 & w \cr \bar{w} & 0}$, and matrices $\pmatrix{0 & w \cr \bar{w} & 0}$ are in the $-1$ eigenspace for the standard Cartain involution $x \to -x^*$ on the Lie algebra. This eigenspace is *not* a Lie subalgebra, so we would not expect its exponentials to be a Lie subgroup.

So, I infer that *something* is ... off.

Comment: Thanks Paul.This question came up to my head when I was reading in a book  about the analytic automorphism group of the unit disc. The author says " Let $G$be the group of transforms of the form $\dfrac{az+b}{\bar bz+\bar a},\ \ |b|<|a|$ and consider the subgroup $S$ consisting of transforms of the form $\dfrac{z+b}{\bar z+1}, \  |b|<1$....  "  So now I think he meant the subgroup "generated by"  not "consisting of"??

Comment: A typo in your comment (missing $\bar{b}$ in the denominator), but, yes, conceivably "subgroup generated by"... but that would actually give all of $SU(1,1)$. But, still, it might not matter for what that author was doing. In fact, the _set_ of such maps has the property that the collection of the images of $0$ under it contains every point of the open unit disk, etc. It's not a subgroup, but it has that property.

Comment: yes there is a typo there but I can't edit my comment anymore now :)  So the author mentioned also something very brief about the Iwasawa Decomposition of $SU(1,1)$. What this decomposition would be? I mean what is the compact subgroup?

Comment: The compact subgroup is $K=\{\pmatrix{\mu & 0 \cr 0 & \bar{\mu}}\}$ with $|\mu|=1$. The parabolic subgroup  $P$ occurring in an Iwasawa decomposition $SU(1,1)=P\cdot K$ is _not_ that set mentioned in your question, since $P$ is a group. A Cayley map that send the disk to the upper half-plane makes $P$ more visible: there, $P$ is upper-triangular matrices in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul for your answers and help,, that is very helpful ,, I appreciate that :)